# pandas inner merging of two different sizes dfs, checking if values of one df is in range of second df and store it into another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two questions, as I am trying to do the following:

1) To perform an inner merge of two different sized data frames to check for intersecting values and store into a third dataframe, the dimension of df1 and df2 are as following: df1.shape is (10000, 1893) and df2.shape is (90000, 1893) with the same column headings.

2) If I want to check by element-wise iteration on how many df2 values will fit into the range interval of df1 values (let's say in the range is between 0.9 * df1 to 1.1 * df1), and afterwards I want to store the match values into a fourth dataframe.

Below is the code of what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', squeeze = True)



           MW            AMW          ...
0          160.17,       8.483,       ...
1          162.20,       7.373,       ...
2          162.16,       7.373,       ...
.          .             .            ...
.          .             .            ...
.          .             .            ...
9997       447.78,       9.329,       ...
9998       447.78,       9.329,       ...
9999       447.78,       9.330,       ...
[10000, 1893]

df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', squeeze = True)

           MW            AMW          ...
0          160.28,       5.724,       ...
1          160.18,       8.009,       ...
2          160.19,       8.009,       ...
.          .             .            ...
.          .             .            ...
.          .             .            ...
89997      447.78,       9.329,       ...
89998      447.78,       9.329,       ...
89999      447.78,       9.329,       ...
[90000, 1893]
```

For the first part, I have tried the following:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner')
print df3

Empty DataFrame Columns: 

[MW, AMW, Sv, Se, Sp, Si, Mv, Me, Mp, Mi, GD, nAT, nSK, nTA, nBT, nBO, nBM, SCBO, RBN, RBF, nAB, nH, nC, nN, nO, nS, nHM, nHet, H%, C%, N%, O%, nCsp3, nCsp2, nCIC, nCIR, TRS, Rperim, Rbrid, MCD, RFD, RCI, NRS, NNRS, nR05, nR06, nR10, nBnz, ARR, D/Dtr05, D/Dtr06, D/Dtr10, ZM1, ZM1V, ZM1Kup, ZM1Mad, ZM1Per, ZM1MulPer, ZM2, ZM2V, ZM2Kup, ZM2Mad, ZM2Per, ZM2MulPer, ON0, ON0V, ON1, ON1V, Qindex, BBI, DBI, SNar, HNar, GNar, Xt, Dz, Ram, BLI, Pol, LPRS, MSD, SPI, PJI2, ECC, AECC, DECC, MDDD, UNIP, CENT, VAR, ICR, SMTI, SMTIV, GMTI, GMTIV, Xu, CSI, Wap, S1K, S2K, ...]
Index: []

[0 rows x 1893 columns]
```

I don't understand why I am getting an empty dataframe in return with only the column headings. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

And for the second part, I have tried to create a function that will check for any values that will fit in the interval ranges (I got this idea from one of the question that I've looked up on stackflow, and the person that answered suggest to do it this way). However, I am still not getting the correct result.

This is my code for the second part:

```
def checkfunc(x, df2):
    idx = df2['MW'] == x['MW']
    df2 = df2.loc[idx]
    check = (df2 >= (x * 0.9)) & (df2 <= (x * 1.1))
    return check.any()

df4 = df2[df2.apply(lambda x: checkfunc(x, df2), axis=1)].drop_duplicates()
print df4
```

For the second part, I am keep getting into a continuous iteration that does not converge at all. I have also take a look at the np.where() and pd.DataFrame.isin() methods, but I was unable to get them to work either. Can anyone suggest a good way to solve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify `on` parameter, then `pd.merge()` merges DataFrames using *all* columns that have *same names* in both DataFrame's.

If you get an empty DF - that means that there are no matching rows (in terms of columns having the same names in both DFs).

Demo:

```
In [4]: d1
Out[4]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [5]: d2
Out[5]:
   A  B   C
0  1  2  30
1  4  5  60

In [6]: pd.merge(d1, d2)
Out[6]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []

In [7]: pd.merge(d1, d2, on=['A','B'])
Out[7]:
   A  B  C_x  C_y
0  1  2    3   30
1  4  5    6   60
```